# Is there any difference to using a br or a div for clearing floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I thought that `<br class="clear">` would add an extra line break, but it doesn't look like there's any difference to it compared to `<div class="clear"></div>` for clearing floats. The `clear` class is defined as follows:

```
.clear {clear:both}
```

Is there any difference between them? Should I just stick with `br` because it's shorter?

Answer (score 1):

They behave identically, but if you're going to use dedicated clearing elements (which in itself is bad practice), you might as well drop the class and use the presentational attribute directly:

```
<br clear="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The <br> tag inserts a single line break.
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

```
The <div> tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.
The <div> tag is used to group block-elements to format them with CSS.
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

the break should only be used to create a line break like hitting enter when typing.  The div is a container to put elements in.  If you want a true line break use br.  if you use div you dont create a line break it may appear so due to padding, margin, etc.

Comment: use 2 <br> tags to end the line and skip the next.